# Check all mallocs if they are protected with NULL return

Tags: c, malloc, c-preprocessor

I have a project that uses malloc a lot. And I wonder if there is a possibility to somehow check if all my mallocs are protected from a **NULL** return? Maybe to define something in header file? I tried to do it myself, checked forums - all in vain. Any possible variants?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. Simply wrap `malloc` is y function of yours and abort (`exit(1)` if `malloc` returns NULL.

Comment: How about `calloc` and `realloc`?

Comment: If you use a wrapper you'll need to pass a location argument as well, so it can report which allocation has failed.

Comment: Great answers, thank you guys

Comment: (evil grin) this is like I like to code in C++... :D

Comment: @SergeyA allocation can still fail with c++ :p

Comment: @SergeyA I have to code it on C =)

Comment: @Fredrik, certainly, but it will (by default) trigger an exception, so you wan't need to manually check for return value.

Comment: Or you can replace malloc with a macro that calls a function which checks all of that.

Comment: Shameless plug, you can use stensal sdk (https://stensal.com) to build your code,  stensal runtime will automatically check all null pointer dereferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace all calls to `malloc` with a wrapper function that performs the necessary NULL check:

```
void *safe_malloc(size_t s)
{
    void *p = malloc(s);
    if (!p) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}
```

You can also do the same for `calloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: Got it, just thought about any ways of checking my mallocs out, but this is a good solution to handle it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Then (after replacement) you would need to check all `safe_malloc` are not needlessly tested for `NULL`. Ah the irony... I am joking (half joking)

Comment: @FyodorIzmalkov If you have the function `safe_malloc` in a separate file, e.g. `safe_malloc.c`, you could use `#define malloc safe_malloc` in `save_malloc.h` and include this only where you want to replace `malloc` with `save_malloc`, not in `safe_malloc.c`. This avoids modifying all `malloc` calls. You only have to replace `#include <malloc.h>` with `#include "safe_malloc.h"` in all C files that use malloc. (except `safe_malloc.c`)

Comment: @Bodo, this is super cunning, good thought, thank you for your advice